# Driver problems with fresh install of Win 7 Home Premium on Toshiba Satellite laptop

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bios, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite L875D-S7332 laptop that had Windows 8 preinstalled on a hard drive that crashed.  I got a new hard drive and installed Windows 7 Home Premium from a DVD.  To do this I had to change the BIOS settings from "UEFI Boot" to "CSM Boot".  The OS installed with no problems, but many devices are not recognized by the OS.  Downloading and installing drivers from Toshiba's web site has not helped.

For example, in the Device Manager the only Display Adapter shown is "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter"; the AMD Radeon™ HD 7520G does not show up, and when I install Catalyst Control Center it says that there is no hardware that can be controlled by that tool.  I have seen some suggestions that the motherboard BIOS is not seeing the GPU BIOS, and that this is not fixable.

I am having the same sort sort of problems with the LAN adapters (both wired and wireless), which makes the computer essentially useless.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What toshiba laptop model are you using?

Comment: Does your laptop even support Windows 7?

Comment: The laptop is a Satellite L875D-S7332

Comment: I found that Toshiba's European website provides Windows 7 drivers that are not available from the US website:
http://www.toshiba.eu/innovation/windows7_drivers.jsp

Comment: I have had nothing but bad luck trying to install windows on a laptop without using the original OEM cdrom.  Personally, I would buy a OEM cd from the manufacturer before I would try that.

Comment: Just FYI, it worked fine.  The Windows 7 drivers from the European support site have the laptop up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Toshiba's European web site has Windows 7 drivers that are not available on their US site:

http://www.toshiba.eu/innovation/windows7_drivers.jsp